# Google analytics event tracking for form on wordpress site

Tags: javascript, wordpress, google-analytics

I'm using a mailchimp plugin for a sign up form on my wordpress site.  This form appears throughout the site, but the source code is in one location.  I would like to track the form as 3 separate events: the sidebar, the footer, and the Take Action page. This is the code for GA event tracking that I am using in the form.

```
<input type="submit" value="Sign up" onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Newsletter', 'Click Sign up', 'Form']);"/>
```

Since I am only working from one form, how do I modify this to include 3 separate events?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure this is what you mean but you can track other events from your form by simply adding extra calls in the on-click separate them with a `;`

```
onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Newsletter', 'Click Sign up', 'Form']);_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Newsletter', 'Click Sign up', 'Form2']);_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Newsletter', 'Click Sign up', 'Form3']);"
```

If what you mean is that you have links/buttons in the footer, sidebar and take action page and want to track when they are clicked.  Then you are going to have to add the code manually to those links probably. I might be able to help with this but i will need more information on how you have those links / buttons set up in wordPress.

Comment: Thank you for the response. It is the same form that appears in the footer, sidebar and take action page, not 3 different forms. I want to include GA event tracking that will generate a report that tells me whether I'm looking at an event triggered from the user clicking on the newsletter sign up button in the footer, the sidebar, or the take action page. There must be some way to to modify the code associated with the sign up button to provide this information.  Is it possible to do within just one form?